# how to get value when function is running on browser

Tags: jquery, html

i have animated div in html. it is adding 1px to div in every second, now i want if my div's right position reach 15 then one alert box should say "hiii". i have made a small function but it is not working.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>

.wrap { border:solid 1px #F00; width:1000px; height:300px; overflow:hidden; position:relative}

.box { width:200px; height:200px; background:#00F; position:absolute}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


var left=5; 

$(function aniMation(){




    $('.box').css({right:++left})
    setTimeout(aniMation,1000)  

    })



$(function (){

    var box= $(".box").css("right")

    if(box=="10px"){

        alert("hiii")

        }


    })





</script>


</head>


<body>

<div class="wrap">

<div class="box"></div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: "It is not working" isn't enough information.  Tell us what you are seeing and why it is wrong.

Comment: sir my animated div moving right in every second, when my div's right position reached 10px nothing happen, it should alert box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're actually calling that function other than on page load!

From the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/%24):

---

## jQuery( callback )

A shorthand for $(document).ready().
Allows you to bind a function to be executed when the DOM document has finished loading.

---

I've checked the lines you call in the Console of my browser (Google Chrome) and they seem to work. The problem is that the function is only executed once on page load, which is before the check is true.

Answer (score 1):

This function is run once when the page is ready, and then never run again:

```
$(function (){
    var box= $(".box").css("right")

    if(box=="10px"){
        alert("hiii")
        }
    })
```

If you want to check the div's position, you have to do it repeatedly, perhaps in the same function that is moving the div.